# AWS Athena SDK with C#, how run DDL instructions?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-net

I using the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Athena/NAthena.html sdk nuget https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/ in order to query S3 bucket files, the thing is I need to create dataCatalog/databases and tables per demand (inside my program), I found a method to create dataCatalogs, but there is no such thing for databases or tables, only query methods. I'm confusing and want to know how can I do such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no specific method for creating databases and tables, for that you will need to use QueryExecution requests

For databases:

```
var query = $"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DatabaseName " +
                "COMMENT 'some comment' " +
                "WITH DBPROPERTIES ('creator'='Me', 'Extra.'='some extra info');";

    var request = new StartQueryExecutionRequest
    {
        QueryString = query,
        ResultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration
        {
            OutputLocation = _settings.DDLOutputLocation
        }
    };
```

For tables:

```
 var query = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                "TableName ( " +
                "column1 int, " +
                "column2 string, " +
                "column3 int, " +
                "column4 binary) " +
                "ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' " +
                $"LOCATION '{_settings.TableDataSourceLocation}'";

    var request = new StartQueryExecutionRequest
    {
        QueryString = query,
        QueryExecutionContext = new QueryExecutionContext
        {
            Catalog = _settings.CatalogName,
            Database = _settings.DatabaseName
        },
        ResultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration
        {
            OutputLocation = _settings.DDLOutputLocation
        }
    };
```